# How can I determine compile-time that a pointer cast will be offsetted

Tags: c++, casting, multiple-inheritance, type-traits, static-assert

There are several ways to detect this at run-time but I cannot find a way to determine if a pointer to a class will be offsetted at compile-time.

```
class MyA
{
public:
    int m_memberI;
};

class MyB
{
public:
    double m_memberD;
};

class MyC : public MyA, public MyB
{
};

void main()
{
    MyC myC;
    void* pVoidB = dynamic_cast< MyB* >( &myC );

    if( pVoidB != &myC )
    {
        std::cout << "Offset needed!" << std::endl;
    }
}

// **********************************************************************************
// Ideally, I would prefer something like this
//
// static_assert( std::cast_needs_offset< MyB*, MyC* >::value, "Offset detected!!!" );
// **********************************************************************************
```

The compilers obviously has that information, but I can't find a type_trait that could help me.

Any trick up your sleeves?

Comment: Rather than template meta-programming, have you tried a `constexpr`-based solution?

Comment: Sounds like an idea, I will try this as soon as I get a hand on a compiler that supports them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found several questions about the same problem. It's not what I want and I cannot use those solutions but after a lot of research, I think it's impossible to accomplish what I am trying to do because first members of each class are unknown at a template library level.

See:

[How to do a static assert that a pointer cast is trivial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535162/how-to-do-a-static-assert-that-a-pointer-cast-is-trivial?rq=1)

and

[C++, statically detect base classes with differing addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131643/c-statically-detect-base-classes-with-differing-addresses)

```
static_assert(offsetof(MyC, m_memberI) == offsetof(MyA, m_memberI));
static_assert(offsetof(MyC, m_memberD) != offsetof(MyB, m_memberD));
```

Unfortunately this is useless for my particular problem.